# A trigonometric function question for calculus

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Compute the definite integral $$\int_0^1 \left(2-x^2\right)^{3/2}dx$$

Please help me, i suppose $x=\sqrt{2} \sin \theta$ but I just couldn't get the answer.

Thank you

Comment: What happened when using your substitution?

Comment: Using that substitution, what does $dx$ need to be?  $dx =  \sqrt 2 \cos \theta$

Comment: If you don't tell us where you get stuck, you won't get the most helpful of answers.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wZSjmZS this is my first try and couldn't figure out where going  wrong .i used another way and got the answer. I wanted to know why this is wrong

Comment: Note: I used Wallis in the process

Comment: @Kizaru: In the second line, you correctly have the upper bound $\pi/4$. In the subsequent integrals, you've changed the upper bound to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly why you're process fails, Kizaru. You can't apply the Wallis formula because of the bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if $x = \sqrt{2} \sin t$ then $2-x^2 = 2 \cos^2 t$, and also $dx = \sqrt{2} \cos t dt$ and you get
$$
\int_0^1 \left(2-x^2\right)^{3/2}dx
 = 2^{3/2} \sqrt{2} \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^4 t dt
 = 4\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^4 t dt
$$
Can you complete this? (Hint: use the relation between $\cos 2x$ and $\cos^2 x$ twice)

(You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/385943/16192) for how to do it if in doubt)

Comment: That all falls out from the mere substitution, and if the asker was stuck on the dx conversion, that was covered.  Chances are you stopped where it gets difficult.

Comment: @amWhy interesting, will update -- thought he made a mistake in substituting -- but it's a standard technique from here and on, tabulated integral really

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wZSjmZS.    This is my original try

Comment: @amWhy updated with the link to stackexchange post how to solve the trig integral

Comment: I used Wallis in the process